# How to get comment, reblog, like counts for a post?

Tags: tumblr

The [Tumblr API](https://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/api/v2) doesn't seem to support certain details for a post: the number of comments, reblogs or likes.

Is it really true that there's no way to get this from the Tumblr API for each post?

Comment: It is true. Comments aren't supported by Tumblr, they are usually a third party service, like Disqus. The number of likes and reblogs are combined into `note count`.

Comment: Here is the corresponding question on the Tumblr API Discussion group which is yet to be answered: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/tumblr-api/PikovGGERJ8

Answer (score 2):

The tumblr API is very limited in how it reports notes. It can send an array of the last 50(?) i think notes, and in each item of the array, it does have some info about what kind of note it was.

From an old app i was working on, each note packet had a "type" that could be "like", "reblog", or "reply".

Comment: The API docs made it seem that way, but in practice when I used 'true' for reblog_info and note_info parameters as the docs suggested, I got no additional arrays in the result.

Comment: Yeah, from my experience with it, it was never a guarantee that you would receive it.